# To modify this keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

How should I replace the `this` with the original calling object? I understand this is a simplified way to present it but I was trying to understand the object that the `this` was referencing to.

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
 list[i].addEventListener("click", liClick);
}

function liClick(){
  this.classList.toggle("done");
}
```

My understanding is that `this` is referring to the `list[i]` which has been clicked, but when I tried with

```
function liClick(){
  list[i].classList.toggle("done");
}
```

it was wrong, how should I modify it? Thanks.

Comment: In `list[i].classList.toggle("done")` from where you are getting value of `i` ? `this` refer to the current context.  [how this works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Please add a reproducible example (including HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("click", liClick);
}

function liClick(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle("done");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` keyword doesn't  refer to list item.

You should pass `list[i]` to function

the function listClick receive event and you can directly access e.target or make callback function and pass item

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
 list[i].addEventListener("click", () => liClick(list[i]) );
}

const liClick = (listItem) => {
  listItem.classList.toggle("done");
}
```

Comment: you can console.log(this) before using it

Comment: *"In es5 this keyword refer to window"*: that is not true for the OP's code.

Comment: OK, but what is the *reason* why `this` is not the list item?

Comment: `In es5 this keyword refers to window.` completely wrong.  `this` is simply the called function's owner - and that is in itself always either is explicitly defined or defaults to the global object. So in case of anonymous function where there is no function owner `this` will refer to `window`  and in arrow function case it refers to `window`.